# Rewriting SQL queries with GROUP BY and without HAVING using a subquery

Tags: sql

SQL queries using `GROUP BY` that does not have a `HAVING` clause can be rewritten using a subquery. One simple example can be the following:

```
select A.a_id, sum(B.b_count) Bsum
from A
left join B on A.a_id = B.a_id
group by A.a_id

select A.a_id, 
(
    select sum(b.b_count) Bsum
    from B 
    where A.a_id = B.a_id
)
from A
```

Can you give me an example when it can not be done? I mean when a `GROUP BY` SQL query without `HAVING` can not be rewritten using subquery behind `SELECT`?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simply not a programming question.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Uh, and what kind of question it is?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be difficult where the you want to aggregate AND group by values in the same table.

```
select A.a_id, sum(B.b_count) Bsum
from A
left join B on A.a_id = B.a_id
group by A.a_id, b.otherVal
```

Comment: ok that is not due to the computation in `group by`, but due to the fact that B table is part of the `group by` clause

Comment: good point, so it's quite trivial to find counter-examples. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I guess the query can be rewritten without `GROUP BY` even in such case: select distinct A1.a_id, B1.a_id,  
(
 select sum(B2.b_count) 
 from A A2
 left join B B2 on A2.a_id = B2.a_id
 where A2.a_id = A1.a_id and B2.a_id = B1.a_id
) Bsum
from A A1
left join B B1 on A1.a_id = B1.a_id

Comment: In the same spirit, I can rewrite your original query with computation behind `GROUP BY`. However, the subquery behind `FROM` would be necessary.

Comment: Surely `Distinct` is just `group by *` by another name!  Maybe if you had a many-to-many relationship between table a and b (via a link table c) and grouped by things in both a and c...