# Example of a query written using sub-queries that can NOT be re-written using JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Some of my coworkers have been using sub-queries in places where you can simply use a join. pros and cons partially discussed [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

Most of their queries can be reduced down to the following pattern:

```
SELECT T1.a, (SELECT T2.b FROM T2 WHERE T2.a = T1.a )
FROM T1
```

which can be re-written as:

```
SELECT T1.a, T2.b
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.a = T2.a
```

Can some awesome SOer give me **an example where sub-queries can be used to implement an algorithm that can't be re-written using joins**?

back story: I find JOINs much easier to read and manage. sql queries written using sub-queries drive me (my subconscious) nuts! I'm trying to find a reason not to hate them so much!

Comment: I was asking a similar question related to subqueries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327267/rewriting-sql-queries-with-group-by-and-without-having-using-a-subquery I believe that every dependent subquery behind `SELECT` can be rewritten into a query without it.

Comment: @RadimBača . . . I'm not sure if what you say is true.  In some cases, writing the equivalent query without a correlated subquery could be very hard and quite non-obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can construct an equivalent query without a subquery, it is more complex than just a `join`:

```
SELECT T1.a, (SELECT SUM(T2.b) FROM T2 WHERE T2.a <= T1.a )
FROM T1;
```